# Что мы делаем с [мойсклад-api]?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, поддержка-продукта-на-so

В последнее всё чаще вижу вопросы про [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api):

- [Поменяли API ключ в интеграции retailCRM + МойСклад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/986668/15479).
- [выгрузка файлов из Мой Склад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982099/15479).
- и т.п. ([все 77 вопросов по 5 меткам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4*+or+moysklad*))

Да, [официально можно использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) SO для поддержки клиентов. Но подобные вопросы, как правило, бесполезны для других. На SOen, вероятно, такое бы закрывали как узкоспециализированные вопросы.

Что-то будем делать с такими вопросами? Просто, к примеру, много подобных вопросов про другие продукты закрываются с текстом "обращайтесь в поддержку".

Comment: И кстати как-то я пробовал все вопросы привести к метке `мойсклад-api`. Так люди из ТП этого сервиса начали всё возвращать на место. И не пойму зачем там куча меток типа `moysklad-pos-api` `moysklad-phone-api` и прочее. Я к тому, что не получается заигнорить метку.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev да там даже Грундий этим страдает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/982099/revisions

Comment: Как раз сам хотел набрать подобный вопрос, ибо, как по мне, со стороны сервиса неправильно посылать своих клиентов на... ruSO, пусть тут, по их словам, и обитает их тех. поддержка...

Comment: @Kir_Antipov по правилам можно, на enSO есть ТП от phpstorm и вопросы довольно популярны. Но тут конечно немного другая ситуация.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev: пусть я не очень люблю как PHP, так и JetBrains, но давайте все таки не будем сравнивать продукты реально массового потребления с безымянным "моим складом") Как показывает практика, им пользуются люди, которые не то что далеки от сего ресурса, но и от мира программирования в целом, так что вопросы от них несут скорее "вредоносный шум", нежели пользу для сообщества

Comment: @Suvitruf, в теории у них несколько видов апи, по метке на каждый вид - 3 или 4 вроде как

Comment: @Grundy там всего ~30 вопросов, зачем настолько сильно метки уточнять -_-

Comment: @Suvitruf, затем что они относятся **к разным** апи.

Comment: @Grundy: Вас самого не раздражает, когда люди начинают по 40 тэгов к вопросу лепить? [tag:c#] [tag:visual-studio] [tag:visual-studio-2015] [tag:visual-studio-2017] [tag:hello-world] [tag:whitespace] [tag:программирование] [tag:intel] [tag:сегодня-на-завтрак-я-ел-бутерброд-может-проблема-в-этом]

Comment: @Grundy ну давайте тогда сделаем [tag:google-api-json], [tag:google-api-protobuf] и т.д.

Comment: @Suvitruf, почему бы и нет?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, 40 тегов к вопросу нельзя прилепить :-) так как ограничение стоит на 5 меток :)

Comment: @Grundy: да я понимаю, я утрирую для наглядности)

Comment: @Grundy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/260198

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, как уже обсуждалось на мете, метки нужны для настройки фильтрации вопросов/ответов, поэтому чем больше будет разнообразие меток, тем лучше будет работать поиск

Comment: @Suvitruf, и к какому пункту ты хочешь притянуть данные метки? :-)

Comment: @Grundy `Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts`.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а ты уверен, что они значат одно и то же? Можешь гарантировать, что эти апи предназначены для одних и тех же задач?

Comment: @Grundy да, для работы со складом.

Comment: @Suvitruf, работа может быть разной, и действия которые можно произвести с разными апи могут отличаться и не перекрываться. Не вижу проблемы в 4 разных метках, если они будут использоваться в соответствии с правилами.

Comment: @Grundy: но не стоит же доводить понятие меток до абсурда! Так и вовсе можно под каждое слово отвести отдельную метку, чтоб поиск стал "ультра-гибким"! `"МойСклад"` не является каким-то распространенным продуктом, чтобы под каждое его телодвижение метки плодить. Да и Вы думаете, что кто-то из задавших вопрос (кроме 3, кажется, относительно устоявшихся участников) вообще будет пользоваться метками?

Comment: @Grundy давайте под каждый endpoint свою метку заводить.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, под каждое слово не получится, смотри выше ссылку от Suvitruf, там указано когда стоит жечь метки. На мой взгляд данные 4 метки под них не подходят.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ты еще скажи давайте для каждого языка программирования свою метку заведем, хотя постойте-ка...

Comment: @Suvitruf, кстати на enSO отдельная метка по protobuf есть.

Comment: Вот ещё откровенный оффтопик из свежего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987122/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%a1

Comment: И ещё из той же оперы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987139

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Спасибо [@AntonMenshov](https://habr.com/ru/company/moysklad/blog/452016/#comment_20263031), модераторам сети и остальным неравнодушным за помощь в этом вопросе.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На [странице МойСклад](https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/topics) теперь нет редиректа на Stack Overflow на Русском.

---

Что же касается вопросов, если они будут появляться в дальнейшем, то относиться к ним как и к остальным вопросам: хорошие оставляем, плохие закрываем.

---

Остаётся только вопрос меток. Его можно обсудить в отдельном треде.

Comment: Ура, товарищи! Это победа!

Answer (score 12):

Стоит отметить, что ресурс Stack Overflow можно использовать не *вместо* специализированного раздела на сайте поставщика продукста, а лишь как дополнение. Отсылать *всех* пользователей с проблемыми на чужой сайт, возможно, не очень красиво по отношению к этим пользователям.

Формально получается, что текущая ситуация подпадает под нарушение [правил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), потому что SO не может быть единственным местом, где следует задавать все технические вопросы о каком-либо продукте. SO не может быть единственной поддержкой.

В настоящем случае, чтобы обойти такое ограничение достаточно либо включить [раздел службы поддержки](https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/topics), либо, если это трудно, можно организовать группу в какой-нибудь социальной сети вроде ВКонтакте или Facebook и дать на неё ссылку со своего сайта.

В таком случае у участников Stack Overflow появится возможность перенаправлять вопросы, не соответствующие формату нашего сайта, в более подходящее место.

Answer (score 4):

Моё мнение такое.

Пусть будут, лишними не будут. Но нужно всё привести к одной метке, предлагаю [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api) и не плодить кучу других меток, они ни к чему.

Comment: Как минимум да, нужно всё к одной метке привести.

Answer (score 4):

> Да, официально можно использовать SO для поддержки клиентов.

С заметными ограничениями (!)

> Но подобные вопросы, как правило, бесполезны для других.

Полезны или нет, это уже пользователям судить. А то с такой аргументацией вы и Брезенхайма и Фонга выпилите - "мне не нужно, значит и другим бесполезно".

> На SOen, вероятно, такое бы закрывали как узкоспециализированные вопросы.

Опять же, в узкоспециализированности самой по себе ничего плохого нет.

> Что-то будем делать с такими вопросами? Просто, к примеру, много подобных вопросов про другие продукты закрываются с текстом "обращайтесь в поддержку".

Предлагаю сменить вектор, и оценивать вопросы именно по их качеству. Так же как вы оцениваете вопросы по темам в которых не разбираетесь (например, нишевые ЯП).

1. Причесать метки (выбрав англ или рус написание).
2. Плюсовать/минусовать/флагать/закрывать в соответствии с качествами отдельных вопросов.
3. Следовать [ответу @mymedia](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9205/177188) (выйти на контакт, указать на правила SO)

Answer (score 2):

Если просмотреть все вопросы по метке [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api), то совсем не сложно будет заметить, что подавляющая их часть задана с аккаунтов-однодневок, то есть людьми, которые далеки от правил нашего ресурса (некоторые и вовсе принимают ruSO за тех. поддержку `"МойСклад"`), что уже не может не говорить о наличии проблемы.

Если посетить раздел поддержки указанного выше инструмента, то там можно наткнуться на следующее сообщение с ссылками на наш ресурс:

> Сообщество разработчиков доступно только для чтения — все технические вопросы следует задавать на Stack Overflow, используя метки:
>
> moysklad-json-api - JSON API
> moysklad-pos-api - POS API
> moysklad-phone-api - Phone API
> moysklad-loyalty-api - Loyalty API

Пусть правилами ruSO и SE в целом данная практика не запрещена, я считаю, что подобное положение дел попросту недопустимо: сторонний сервис поленился создать на базе своей платформы адекватную поддержку и пополняемый FAQ и решил согнать всех людей, у которых возникли проблемы с их инструментами, к нам.

Подчеркну, что `"МойСклад"` не является каким-то продуктом *массового потребления* (к примеру, посты по поводу настройки/использования всевозможных IDE находят широкий отклик на платформе), а вопросы, к нему относящиеся, которые на данный момент можно найти на ruSO, создают больше вредоносного шума, нежели вносят хоть какой-то адекватный вклад в сообщество.

---

Я предлагаю следующее: стоит полностью очистить ruSO от вопросов и меток, которые относятся к `"МойСклад"`, пока они не расплодились в немыслимых количествах.
Попутно следует обратиться к владельцам данного инструмента, дабы они пересмотрели свою позицию и организовали вменяемый FAQ в рамках своей же платформы, чтобы не возникало надобности куда-то перенаправлять своих клиентов.
Это сыграет на руку как `StackOverflow на русском`, которому не придется претерпевать поток уж слишком узконаправленных вопросов низкого качества, так и, собственно, самому `"МойСклад"`, пользователи которого перестанут чувствовать себя совершенно потерянными в бескрайних просторах незнакомого им ресурса.

Однако, как бы там ни было, от обилия меток нужно избавляться точно и уже сейчас, ибо их у нас уже как минимум 5 штук!

Comment: Только надо сначала связаться с владельцами сайта продукта и объяснить им ситуацию, чтобы они исправили свой раздел поддержки. Пока этого не будет сделано, тереть бесполезно. Только надо определиться, Николас ли это должен делать как официальное лицо ресурса или кто-то другой.

Comment: @Arhad: точно, спасибо! А то меня все не покидало чувство, что я забыл очем-то написать хД

Comment: @Arhad метки можно сжечь уже сейчас. Оставить только одну [tag:мойсклад-api]. И дело даже не в складе, эти метки просто слишком уточняющие, их в любом случае нужно сжечь.

Comment: @Suvitruf Опять же, перед сжиганием меток надо добиться их слияния в том самом разделе. А то получится, что в их справке одно, а по факту другое. Не по-человечески как-то по отношению к приходящим оттуда.

Comment: @Arhad ну, с этим лучше Николасу разобраться.

Comment: То, что этот Склад "не является продуктом массового потребления" - не повод удалять вопросы по нему или сжигать метки. Нет такого правила. А 5 меток, которые они создали - в буквальном смысле капля в море. Удаление конкретных меток не приведет ни к чему, кроме того, что пользователи станут использовать бессмысленные обобщенные метки, вроде [api], [запрос] и т.п.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: ну так а почему тогда какой-нибудь условной парихмахерской не согнать сюда всех своих клиенток, чтобы мы созерцали вопросы в духе "Как записать к Жанночке через API на 14:30"? Дело не столько в том, что продукт слишком узконаправленный, сколько в том, что подобная его политика приводит к появлению у нас вопросов, которые с программированием чаще всего связаны, мягко говоря, посредственно, от людей, которые вообще не понимают, что из себя представляет ruSO

Comment: @Arhad "не по человечески" то что они сделали. А эти метки можно засинонимить.

Answer (score 0):

Выскажусь по количеству меток, привязанных к одному продукту.

У нас имеется куча меток по git: `git-push`, `git-branch`, `git-merge` и т. д. Мне это не нравится, я бы ограничился одной, просто git. Однако, прецедент создан, теперь расхлёбывайте: на каждую утилитку/библиотечку можно лепить кучу меток.

Подумываю о создании меток на операторы языков программирования: `c#-for`, `c#-if` и т. д. А также `c++-for`, `c++-if`, `java-for`, `java-if`... (шутка)

Comment: похоже, это сообщение не отвечает на поставленный вопрос в начале темы

Answer (score -1):

Так как есть [официальные правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) по использовании SO в качестве поддержки ничего из ряда вон выходящего не происходит.

Достаточно проверить, какому типу соответствует вопрос

> - Как мне? – спрашивайте на Stack Overflow на русском (скажите пользователям, какие метки использовать, как минимум, метку вашей продукции);
> - У меня возникла эта ошибка, в чем причина? – спрашивайте на Stack Overflow на русском;
> - У меня эта ошибка и я уверен что это баг – сообщайте про нее на вашем сайте;
> - У меня есть идея/запрос функции – сообщайте про нее на вашем сайте;
> - Почему вы...? – спрашивайте в вашем сообществе (на форуме поддержки и пр.);
> - Когда вы...? – спрашивайте в вашем сообществе.

И в соответствие с местом задания либо закрыть, либо оставить как есть.

---

Метки очевидно сделаны под конкретные виды `api`, следовательно *желательно* оставить их в соответствии с тем, что указано в справке

```
moysklad-json-api - JSON API
moysklad-pos-api - POS API
moysklad-phone-api - Phone API
moysklad-loyalty-api - Loyalty API
```

Остальные удалить. Проблема с этим в том, что кроме поддержки, мало кто может определить к какому именно типу апи относится вопрос, соответственно стоит предложить им пройтись по существующим вопросам и проставить необходимые метки и удалить ненужные.

Comment: На каком основании какая-то справка на стороннем ресурсе устанавливает нормативы на нашем сайте в обход принятых правил? Ну по-уродски же выглядит *"moysklad"*, мы всегда в названиях русский язык предпочитаем!..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ни на каком, поэтому в ответе и указано _желательно_, так как люди приходящие из их справки, скорее всего будут ставить метки, которые указаны там.

Comment: Пусть ставят, для того у нас и придуманы синонимы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, синонимы это выход, просто пока были предложения именно **удалить** метки, а не синонимизировать.

Comment: "Удалить" - цель, "синонимизировать" - средство.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так при синонимизации не происходит удаление ж :)

Comment: При синонимизации метка перестаёт появляться.

Comment: Но при этом ее еще можно ставить на вопрос, хоть при сохранении она и поменяется на синоним. Без синонима, с каждым новым вопросом есть риск получить эти метки обратно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov при объединении перестанет. При просто синонимизации нет.